# Check if exist each one row Separately and run the same code

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have two tables i want to check if exist Barcode from first Table to Second. But i want run the code only for the first row. When it will end then to run the same code for the second row and making the same for rest of my rows till it will end.

Here is an example of my code which i want to use: But How will i run the code for each row separately.Starting with first then with second,third and go on.

Code: For SQL

```
IF EXISTS ( SELECT Barcode FROM Table_1 where barcode = (select barcode from Table_2)
BEGIN
update Table_2 set Name = (select Name from Table_1)
END

ELSE
BEGIN
insert into Table_2 (Barcode,Name) (select Barcode,name from Table1)
END
```

[image]

Code: For C#

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand CheckNone = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand("IF EXISTS( SELECT Barcode FROM Table_1 where barcode = (select barcode from Table_2) SELECT 1 ELSE SELECT 0", con);
con.Open();

var result = (int)CheckNone.ExecuteScalar();
if (result == 0)
{

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into Table_2 (Barcode,Name) (select Barcode,name from Table1)",con);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
con.Close();
}
else
{
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("update Table_2 set Name = (select Name from Table_1)",con);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
}
}
```

Comment: Your queries are running against _the entire table_, not just one row - remember that SQL is set-based, so processing "one row at a time" is not what SQL is designed for.

Comment: Also, why do you need the Name field in Table2 when you can get it from Table1 and you have to sync it up?  Why not just do a join and get it from Table1?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you just need to update the `Name` in Table 2 for rows with matching `Barcode` values in Table 1.  You can to that for the entire table in teo queries:

```
UPDATE t2
SET Name = t1.Name
FROM Table2 t2
INNER JOIN Table1 t1
  ON t2.Barcode = t1.Barcode

INSERT INTO Table2
(Barcode, Name)
SELECT Barcode, Name
FROM Table1
WHERE Barcode NOT IN
(SELECT Barcode FROM Table2)
```

If you *really* want to update one row at a time, then just add `WHERE Barcode = @barcode` to your SELECT queries and pass the paramater value to the Command in  C#.  Note however that it will be MUCH slower than doing it all at once.

Comment: Look this is an example.My code is much more complicated. For succeeding what i want do i must  run same code for each sql row separately.

Comment: @DiH OK then just add a `WHERE Barcode = @barcode` filter clause to your queries and pass in the "current" barcode from C#.